# Determine the angle between the two lines $L₁$ and $L₂$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Determine the **angle between** the two lines L₁ and L₂:

$$L₁: {(α+u(μ-α),β+u(ρ-β)),u∈(0,1)}$$
$$L₂:{(α₁+v(μ₁-α₁),β₁+v(ρ₁-β₁)),v∈(0,1)}$$

where $α,μ,β,ρ,α₁,μ₁,β₁,ρ₁$ are constants.

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture and use trigonometry. Also refer to [here](https://www.google.si/#q=angle+between+two+lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  If you are willing to assume they meet at all, just find a vector along each line.  To get a vector along $L_1$, take two values of $u$ and find the vector between the two points.  Now take the dot product of those two vectors and divide by the product of their magnitudes.  You are left with the cosine of the angle between the vectors.